# The cyclic group $(\Bbb{Z}_n, +)$ of order $n\ge2$ has exactly one generator if and only if the group is $(\Bbb{Z}_2, +)$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

For a cyclic group $(\Bbb{Z}_n, +)$ of order $n\ge2$, there exists an element $g$ of $(\Bbb{Z}_n, +)$ such that $\{g^n: n\text{ is an element of }\Bbb{Z}\} = (\Bbb{Z}_n, +)$. Such an element $g$ is called a generator of the cyclic group.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Usually for additive groups one writes $ng$ rather than $g^n$.  Consider using $m$ instead of $n$ for the group generated by $g$, since you used $n$ for the order of the cyclic group.   If $g$ is a generator, then so is $-g$, and $g\ne-g$ if $n>2$

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be cyclic group of order $n\in\mathbb N$, $n>2$. Let be $g\in G$ a generator. Then $g^{-1}$ is a generator, too, and $g \neq g^{-1}$ because otherwise $g$ would be of order $2$.